# Глюки в Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk, apk

Пишу приложение на Android, тестирую проделанную работу на физическом устройстве. Все было отлично, но в какой то момент студия перестала заливать приложение с изменениями в телефон. После нажатия кнопки Run все происходит как обычно, приложение запускается, но без каких либо изменений. 
У кого то так было? Как вы исправляли эту проблему?

P.S. Раньше было такое иногда, но после того как строил APK и переустанавливал проходило, сейчас никак. Студию перезагружал, телефон тоже.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас вторая версия студии и включена опция `InstantRun`. Вам надо пойти в настройки и выключить её.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Эта функция отлично работала. Она не стабильна ?

Comment: @AmirShabanov, лично я сразу её отключил, ибо начитался о проблемах с ней и не желал пытаться в них вникнуть в виду новизны этой фичи и неизбежных с ней проблем.